# How to implement a table with 6 foreign keys in Laravel having many to many relationship

Tags: laravel

[image]

I am new to Laravel. I came across a situation where I need to use 6 foreign keys in a table. But I don't have any idea about how to implement it in Laravel.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Welcome. What do you have so far, can you post your migrations and any errors that occur? Documentation on [Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) didn't help?

Comment: did the answer below help you solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, There's no problem with migration. That's all done. I don't have any error in migration. My problem is retrieving data(in index view) from database after entering the details to database. Since I am using 6 foreign keys with many to many relationship, i do not know how to fetch data in this scenario. Should my table be a Pivot table or simple table? Can I implement a pivot table in Laravel with 6 foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
$table->foreign('ministry_id')->references('id')->on('ministries');
$table->foreign('designation_id')->references('id')->on('designations')->nullable();
...
```